# Select a table cell element and submit it in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table that is dynamically generated with jQuery, it has 3 `td` cells, with 10 values (returned by the server) in each cell. I want to select one of those values and submit it as part of a form. How should I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each value inside those td's in a span and give the td's a class. You could put each value in a different hidden field, on click.

```
$("td.col1 span").click(function ()){
$("#var1").val(this);
}

<input type="hidden" name="var1" id="var1"/>
```

And then subit the form when 3 are selected.

//jquery

```
if(var1 != "" && var2 != "" && var3 != ""){
   $("#formId').submit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was kinda stuck here, this helped me unlock my brain... Cheers!